# Shortened comma-delimited options

Tags: commas

Consider the following sentence:

> Visit our website to join the chat, find upcoming rides, charge
>   locations, and more!

Should I be saying

> Visit our website to join the chat, find upcoming rides and charge
>   locations, and more!

instead, or can "find" be implicitly applied to the 2 following options without repeating it like in the original sentence? "And more" wouldn't necessarily be associated with "find". Or should I make it clearer with

> Visit our website to find upcoming rides, charge locations, join the
>   chat, and more!

Basically, my objective is to include those 4 options, ideally, in the original order, in the shortest, yet, clearest, wording possible.

Comment: Writing advice may be off-topic. How you structure the sentence to convey the intended meaning in the best possible way is up to your creativity. See also [writers.se]

Comment: I've **not** voted to close this post.

Comment: The biggest ambiguity I see in your sentence involves whether you are inviting site visitors to "find charge locations" or to "charge locations" (to their credit cards or like a bull or with a crime, for example).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to be a request for writing advice (effectively in the form of a question, "which of these three formulations is best?"), which is off-topic at this site.

Comment: @SvenYargs I accepted an answer a week ago, so yes, the question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your second version clearest with the double use of 'and', even if it's slightly less peppy.

With the first sentence I initially (wrongly) read 'charge' as a verb in a series of verbs; join, find, charge. In the third example I feel you also need an 'and' in the phrase 'find upcoming rides (and) charge locations'.